# How to identify repeated words as well as position and number of repeats in sentences

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a datset consisting of sentences with *consecutive word repeats*:

**DATA**:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Turn = c("oh is that that steak i got the other night",       # that that
           "no no no i 'm dave and you 're alan",               # no no no
           "yeah i mean the the film was quite long though",    # the the
           "it had steve martin in it it 's a comedy"))         # it it
```

**OBJECTIVE**:

What I'd like to obtain are three more columns added to this dataframe:

- `df$rep_Word`: a column specifying the word that gets repeated
- `df$rep_Pos`: a column specifying the first position in the sentence at which the word is repeated
- `df$rep_Numb`: a column specifying the number of times the word gets repeated

So the expected dataframe looks like this:

**EXPECTED RESULT**:

```
df
                                            Turn rep_Word rep_Pos rep_Numb
1    oh is that that steak i got the other night     that       4        1
2            no no no i 'm dave and you 're alan       no       2        2
3 yeah i mean the the film was quite long though      the       5        1
4       it had steve martin in it it 's a comedy       it       7        1
```

**ATTEMPTED SOLUTION SO FAR**:

My hunch is that the sought information on repeated word, and position and number of repeats can be approached with `strsplit` and the function `duplicated`, e.g., thus:

```
df_split <- apply(df, 2, function(x) strsplit(x, "\\s"))

df_split
$Turn
$Turn[[1]]
 [1] "oh"    "is"    "that"  "that"  "steak" "i"     "got"   "the"   "other" "night"
$Turn[[2]]
 [1] "no"   "no"   "no"   "i"    "'m"   "dave" "and"  "you"  "'re"  "alan"
$Turn[[3]]
 [1] "yeah"   "i"      "mean"   "the"    "the"    "film"   "was"    "quite"  "long"   "though"
$Turn[[4]]
 [1] "it"     "had"    "steve"  "martin" "in"     "it"     "it"     "'s"     "a"      "comedy"
```

For example, for the first sentence in `df`, `duplicated`shows which word gets repeated (namely the one for which `duplicated` evaluates to `TRUE`) and both number and position of the repeat could also be read-off that information:

```
duplicated(df_split$Turn[[1]])
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

The problem is that I don't know how to operationalize `duplicated`in such a way as to obtain the desired added columns in `df`. Help with that endeavor is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another way to solve your problem.

```
df <- data.frame(
  Turn = c("oh is that that steak i got the other night",  # that that
           "no no no i 'm dave and you 're alan",               # no no no
           "yeah i mean the the film was quite long though",    # the the
           "it had steve martin in it it 's a comedy",         # it it)
           "it had steve martin in in it it 's a comedy",
           "yeah i mean the film was quite long though", 
           "hi hi then other words and hi hi again",
           "no no no i 'm dave yes yes and you 're alan no no no no"))  # no no no and no no no no

library(data.table)
cols <- c("rep_Word", "rep_Pos", "rep_Numb")
setDT(df)[, (cols) := {
  words <- strsplit(as.character(Turn), " ")[[1]]
  idx <- rleid(words)
  check <- duplicated(idx)
  chg <- check - shift(check, fill = FALSE)
  starts <- which(chg == 1)
  aend <- if(sum(chg) == 0L) which(chg == -1) else c(which(chg == -1), length(chg) + 1L)
  freq <- aend - starts
  wrd <- words[starts]
  no_dup_default <- .(.(NA_character_), .(NA_integer_), .(NA_integer_))
  if(length(wrd)) .(.(wrd), .(starts), .(freq)) else no_dup_default
}, seq.int(nrow(df))]


df
#                                                       Turn   rep_Word  rep_Pos rep_Numb
# 1:             oh is that that steak i got the other night       that        4        1
# 2:                     no no no i 'm dave and you 're alan         no        2        2
# 3:          yeah i mean the the film was quite long though        the        5        1
# 4:                it had steve martin in it it 's a comedy         it        7        1
# 5:             it had steve martin in in it it 's a comedy      in,it      6,8      1,1
# 6:              yeah i mean the film was quite long though         NA       NA       NA
# 7:                  hi hi then other words and hi hi again      hi,hi      2,8      1,1
# 8: no no no i 'm dave yes yes and you 're alan no no no no  no,yes,no  2, 8,14    2,1,3
#                

# or
df[, lapply(.SD, unlist), seq.int(nrow(df))][, -1]
#                                                        Turn rep_Word rep_Pos rep_Numb
#  1:             oh is that that steak i got the other night     that       4        1
#  2:                     no no no i 'm dave and you 're alan       no       2        2
#  3:          yeah i mean the the film was quite long though      the       5        1
#  4:                it had steve martin in it it 's a comedy       it       7        1
#  5:             it had steve martin in in it it 's a comedy       in       6        1
#  6:             it had steve martin in in it it 's a comedy       it       8        1
#  7:              yeah i mean the film was quite long though     <NA>      NA       NA
#  8:                  hi hi then other words and hi hi again       hi       2        1
#  9:                  hi hi then other words and hi hi again       hi       8        1
# 10: no no no i 'm dave yes yes and you 're alan no no no no       no       2        2
# 11: no no no i 'm dave yes yes and you 're alan no no no no      yes       8        1
# 12: no no no i 'm dave yes yes and you 're alan no no no no       no      14        3
```

Answer (score 2):

The `duplicated` will count four "it" in row 4. Therefore it might be better to use `rle`.

```
v.rle <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$Turn), " "), rle)
v.rle.l <- mapply(`[`, v.rle, "lengths")
v.rle.v <- mapply(`[`, v.rle, "values")
res <- within(df, {
  rep_Pos <- mapply(function(x) el(which(x > 1)) + 1, v.rle.l)
  rep_Numb <- mapply(`[`, v.rle.l, rep_Pos - 1) - 1
  rep_Word <- mapply(`[`, v.rle.v, rep_Pos - 1)
})
res
#                                             Turn rep_Word rep_Numb rep_Pos
# 1    oh is that that steak i got the other night     that        1       4
# 2            no no no i 'm dave and you 're alan       no        2       2
# 3 yeah i mean the the film was quite long though      the        1       5
# 4       it had steve martin in it it 's a comedy       it        1       7
```

**Edit**

To adequately account for the occurrence of multiple duplicates in a row or for the case of no duplicates you may want to use the adapted version below. It displays positions and words with a colon if there are multiple dupes, or yields `NA` in the case of no dupe.

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  Turn = c("oh is that that steak i got the other night",  # that that
           "no no no i 'm dave and you 're alan",          # no no no
           "yeah i mean the film was quite long though",                ## the the
           "it had steve martin in in it it 's a comedy"))              ## in in, it it

v.rle <- lapply(STRSP <- strsplit(as.character(df2$Turn), " "), rle)
v.rle.l <- mapply(`[`, v.rle, "lengths")
v.rle.v <- mapply(`[`, v.rle, "values")

res <- within(df2, {
  rep_Pos <- mapply(function(x) {
    w <- which(x > 1) + 1
    if (length(w) == 0) NA 
    else if (length(w) > 1) cbind(w + seq(w) - 1)
    else w
  }, v.rle.l)
  rep_Numb <- mapply(function(x) cbind(x[x > 1]), v.rle.l)
  rep_Numb[lengths(rep_Numb) == 0] <- NA
  rep_Word <- sapply(mapply(`[`, STRSP, lapply(rep_Pos, `-`, 1)), cbind)
})
res
#                                          Turn rep_Word rep_Numb rep_Pos
# 1 oh is that that steak i got the other night     that        1       4
# 2         no no no i 'm dave and you 're alan       no        2       2
# 3  yeah i mean the film was quite long though       NA       NA      NA
# 4 it had steve martin in in it it 's a comedy   in, it     1, 1    6, 8
```

Comment: I get this error: `within(df, {
+   rep_Pos <- mapply(function(x) which(x > 1) + 1, v.rle.l)
+   rep_Numb <- mapply(`[`, v.rle.l, pos - 1) - 1
+ })
Error in .Primitive("[")(dots[[1L]][[2L]], dots[[2L]][[2L]]) : 
  only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts`

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann I just fixed a typo in the code, does it work now?

Comment: Yes, it does but `df$rep_Word` is missing from the output. Can you update your answer to include it in `df`?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann You're right, I must have overlooked that :) See edit please.

Comment: It works now for the small snippet of data. But I get an error  for the actual (much larger) dataset: `within(df, {
+   rep_Pos <- mapply(function(x) which(x > 1) + 1, v.rle.l)
+   rep_Numb <- mapply(`[`, v.rle.l, rep_Pos - 1) - 1
+   rep_Word <- mapply(`[`, v.rle.v, rep_Pos - 1)
+ })
Error in rep_Pos - 1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator`. Any help with that?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann Yes, there might be duplicates of different words in one row, can you confirm that?

Comment: That's quite possible, yes.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann I've fixed the code now so it counts (just) the first word that is duplicated. Should not throw an error anymore.

Comment: Well done--works now on the larger dataset too. BUT: how can I access the data? When I call `df`, I only get `Turn` but not the three new columns. Where are they stored?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann just assign it to something, `res <- within(.)`, see edit.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. All answers are really great. Yours has the advantage of being sparse.

Comment: Just one more thing: the updated solution counts just the first word that is duplicated but not a potential second other word duplicated. My guess is that this scenario is rather rare. I'd like to be sure though just *how* rare (or common) it is. How could the number of those cases be established?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann Yeah just noted that myself, try the adapted version I just added as an edit.

Comment: Wow! I'm utterly impressed! Thank you so much

Comment: Hi, upon dealing with your answer in earnest, I discovered a small mistake in the resulting dataframe `res`: where there is more than 1 duplicate in `Turn`, the position of the repetition is invariable short by 1. For example, line 4 in `res`is this: `# 4 it had steve martin in in it it 's a comedy   in, it     1, 1    7, 9`but **should be** `# 4 it had steve martin in in it it 's a comedy   in, it     1, 1    6, 8`. I'd be super grateful if you could let me know how to fix this.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann In the `else if` I subtracted 1, would that work for you now?

Answer (score 2):

One `purrr`, `dplyr` and `tibble` option could be:

```
bind_cols(df, 
          map_dfr(strsplit(df$Turn, " ", fixed = TRUE), 
                  ~ enframe(., value = "rep_word") %>%
                   group_by(rleid = with(rle(rep_word), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))) %>%
                   filter(n() > 1) %>%
                   summarise(rep_word = first(rep_word),
                             rep_pos = nth(name, 2),
                             rep_number = n()-1) %>%
                   select(-rleid) %>%
                   summarise_all(toString)))

                                            Turn rep_word rep_pos rep_number
1    oh is that that steak i got the other night     that       4          1
2            no no no i 'm dave and you 're alan       no       2          2
3 yeah i mean the the film was quite long though      the       5          1
4       it had steve martin in it it 's a comedy       it       7          1
```

Comment: I get this error: `Error in strsplit(df$Turn, " ", fixed = TRUE) : non-character argument`

Comment: You need to import your data using `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a super base answer that relies on converting the words to a factor. It also addresses 1) sentences that have no repeated words and 2) sentences that have different words repeated multiple times.

```r
   ID                                                    Turn rep_Word rep_Pos rep_Numb
1   1             oh is that that steak i got the other night     that       4        1
2   2                     no no no i 'm dave and you 're alan       no       2        2
3   3          yeah i mean the the film was quite long though      the       5        1
4   4                it had steve martin in it it 's a comedy       it       7        1
5   5             it had steve martin in in it it 's a comedy       in       6        1
6   5             it had steve martin in in it it 's a comedy       it       8        1
7   6              yeah i mean the film was quite long though     <NA>      NA        0
8   7                  hi hi then other words and hi hi again       hi       2        1
9   7                  hi hi then other words and hi hi again       hi       8        1
10  8 no no no i 'm dave yes yes and you 're alan no no no no       no       2        2
11  8 no no no i 'm dave yes yes and you 're alan no no no no      yes       8        1
12  8 no no no i 'm dave yes yes and you 're alan no no no no       no      14        3
```

Code to make above:

```r
l = list("oh is that that steak i got the other night",       # that that
            "no no no i 'm dave and you 're alan",               # no no no
            "yeah i mean the the film was quite long though",    # the the
            "it had steve martin in it it 's a comedy",         # it it)
         "it had steve martin in in it it 's a comedy",
         "yeah i mean the film was quite long though", 
         "hi hi then other words and hi hi again",
         "no no no i 'm dave yes yes and you 're alan no no no no")

n = length(l)
ans = vector('list', length = n)

for (i in seq_len(n)){
  sentence = l[[i]]
  words_fct = factor(strsplit(sentence, " ", fixed = TRUE)[[1L]])
  levs = as.integer(words_fct)
  inds = which(diff(levs) == 0L)

  rep_Numb = length(inds)
  if (length(rep_Numb > 1L)) {
    diffs = diff(inds) 
    diffs_eq_1 = diffs == 1L
    if (all(diffs_eq_1)) {
      inds = inds[1L]
    } else {
      inds = inds[c(TRUE, !diffs_eq_1)]
      sums = cumsum(diffs_eq_1)
      rep_Numb = c(sums[!diffs_eq_1], sums[length(sums)]) - c(0L, sums[!diffs_eq_1]) + 1L
    }
  }
  ans[[i]] = data.frame(ID = i,
                        Turn = sentence,
                        rep_Word = levels(words_fct)[levs[inds]],
                        rep_Pos = inds + 1L,
                        rep_Numb)
}

do.call(rbind, ans)
```

Comment: Does this solution also account for sentences where more than one word is duplicated, as in `yeah yeah that 's right told told you`?

Comment: Yes? What's the expected result?

Comment: But in the answer you say "For #2, this chooses the first word duplicated"; that is, it only counts, in the above example, `yeah yeah` but ignores `told told`, correct?

Comment: Well, I said ```yes?``` because there was no expected output for that scenario. What is the expected result of ```hi hi then other words and hi hi again```

Comment: I edited to include multiple instances. Instead of pasting the results together, this includes a row for each duplicated word.